# R: Loop through possible combinations of multiple time series vectors to calculate DTW

Tags: r, time-series, dtw

I am new to R and time series. Lets say I have 5 time series vectors (with different lengths) that I want to find the similarity between them using dynamic time warping. As you know, DTW only compares 2 time series. I need to go through each pair of the 5 visits (10 pairs) to calculate the distances then compare them.

Using [DTW package](https://dtw.r-forge.r-project.org), this code works only for two time series.

```
v1<-c(358.214, 359.240, 360.039, 361.163, 361.164, 362.113, 362.114)
v2<-c(392.664, 414.588, 414.589, 421.463, 421.464, 427.863)
v3<-c(470.776, 470.777, 471.951, 471.952, 477.651, 477.652, 479.601, 479.602, 480.426, 480.427)
v4<-c(639.000, 650.574, 650.575, 658.199, 658.200, 658.696)
v5<-c(678.846, 678.847, 688.121, 688.122, 690.371, 690.372, 701.946, 701.947, 704.921)

dtw1 <-dtw(v1, v2, dist.method="Euclidean", keep.internals = T, step.pattern= asymmetric)
plot(dtw1)
```

I don't know how to go through each pair. I don't think for loop is the best option here. After calculating the distances should I store them in matrix to compare them?
What is the best way to calculate all possible pairs for these vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the vectors in a list and use `combn` to create all possible combinations of them and store the result in a list.

```
library(dtw)

list_vec <- list(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)

result <- combn(list_vec, 2, function(x) {
   dtw(x[[1]], x[[2]], dist.method="Euclidean", 
       keep.internals = TRUE, step.pattern= asymmetric)
}, simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean store the result here in the code in (list_results <- list(result)? How can I get the distances from each combination?

Comment: The data is already in list `result`. How do you get distance from `dtw1` in your question? You can use `lapply` to do the same from `result`.

Comment: I use (dtw1$distance). But here for somehow the result is empty. The distance is NULL. I only see 6 combinations (showing the lengths of the vectors for example, (Alignment size (query x reference): 138 x 154)) when I print the result. Do you have any idea of this problem?

Comment: `sapply(result, \`[[\`, 'distance')` Or `sapply(result, function(x) x$distance)` gives me 10 values `310.523  797.915 1999.422 2297.850  358.555 1391.838 1650.420 1679.654 2097.620  227.807`

Comment: Sorry, I noticed I missed one vector. Thats why I only got 6. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to print a matrix here that shows each distance belongs to what pair of vectors?

Comment: You can create those pairs with `tmp <- combn(paste0('v', 1:5), 2, paste0, collapse = '-')`. So maybe add them in a dataframe. `data <- data.frame(pair = tmp, distance = sapply(result, \`[[\`, 'distance'))`